# Bootstrap Change active to disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How would I change have the "On" Button Change to the "Off" from:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-info btn-sm active">On</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-info btn-sm disabled">Off</a>
```

Comment: I am not completely fluent in Javascript,
what would the <script></script> part look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)**:

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of
>   matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the
>   value of the switch argument.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.active,.disabled').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active disabled');
    });
});
</script>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/staUm/)**

Comment: Thanks! the "off" button seems to be unclickable, how would I make this button clickable?

Comment: Did you check my demo?

Comment: Oh, apparently, having the "disabled" tag in bootstrap makes the button unclickable

Comment: Yes it works! I changed the class name to "on" and "off" instead of active and disabled.

Comment: The "disabled" tag in bootstrap makes the button unclickable, thereby the delay doesnt seem to help. I think I will have to fade or change the button color.

Answer (score 2):

> use this to change On to Off
>
> $('.active').addClass('disabled').removeClass('active').html('Off');
>
> use this to change Off to On
>
> $('.disabled').addClass('active').removeClass('disabled').html('On');

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('.active').addClass('disabled').removeClass('active').html('Off');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XD8rG/2/)**